# Why do I have a shared cache when I `jQuery.extend` two objects with the same caching object?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I can explain the problem best with this simple code snippet:

```
    var child1 = {name: 'child1'};
    var child2 = {name: 'child2'};

    var parent = {
        _cache: [],  // storage var
        writeCache: function(key, val)
        {
            console.log('writing cache::'+this.name);
            this._cache[key] = val;
        },
        readCache: function(key)
        {
            if(this._cache[key] == undefined)
            {
                return false;
            }
            return this._cache[key];
        },
    };
    jQuery.extend(child1, parent);
    jQuery.extend(child2, parent);

    child1.writeCache('myKey', 123);

    console.log(child1.readCache('myKey'));  // returns 123 as expected

    console.log(child2.readCache('myKey'));  // returns 123 unexpectedly (for me at least)
```

See this last line:

```
    console.log(child2.readCache('myKey'));
```

Now why does it return 123 when we've accessed only child1's writeCache()?

Comment: This looks like it's about jQuery's extend method, not Javascript inheritance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

jQuery's extend method makes a copy of everything in the second object and puts it in the first object.

That includes copying **the reference** to the array you assign to `parent._cache`. As a result, whenever you read or write from any objects cache, you access the same data store.

To avoid this, make a deep copy.

```
jQuery.extend(true, child1, parent);
jQuery.extend(true, child2, parent);
```

As an aside, since you are dealing with named keys, use an Object, not an Array.

```
_cache: {},  // storage var
```

Answer (score 1):

The `_cache` from `parent` is copied to both child objects. So essentially, the following happens:

```
child1._cache = parent._cache
child2._cache = parent._cache
```

But now they both refer to the same array in memory (js passes the same reference). So when you change one, you should expect it to be reflected elsewhere. For example:

```
parent = {_cache:[]}
child1 = {}
child2 = {}

child1._cache = parent._cache
child2._cache = parent._cache

child1._cache.push(9)
child2._cache; // [9]
```

You can fix this with prototypal inheritance:

```
function parent(){
   this._cache = [];
}
parent.prototype.writeCache = ...
parent.prototype.readCache = ...

child1 = new parent();
child2 = new parent();

child1.writeCache('myKey', 123);

console.log(child1.readCache('myKey')); // 123
console.log(child2.readCache('myKey')); // undefined (/false in your case)
```

You could also use `Object.create` with the original code:

```
child1 = Object.create(parent, {_cache: { value:[] }} )
child2 = Object.create(parent, {_cache: { value:[] }} )
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But see what Quentin suggested. Very easy solution without modifying a lot of code.

Comment: @AbhimanyuGrover, that's true. I just don't think using jquery's extend is a good pattern for inheritance. It certainly isn't better than my prototypal solution in terms of memory usage, since it copies those functions to every child, whereas the prototype doesn't.

Answer (score 1):

`jQuery.extend` has nothing to do with inheritance. It merges the properties of the second object to the first one. This means that the reference to your `_cache` is both in `child1` and `child2`.

Read http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.extend/.

Answer (score 1):

You get the result because the `_cache`-member of `parent` is copied by reference in your example. If you look at the API-docs for jQuery, you can force a deep copy by passing `true` as the first argument to `jQuery.extend`.

See a working jsFiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/mLfUE/

Answer (score 0):

This is about [jQuery's extend method](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.extend/) rather than something that is built in to Javascript.

In this case, you are using .extend() to extend the child2 object with the properties of the parent object.

The jQuery documentation for .extend() mentions at one point:

> The merge performed by $.extend() is not recursive by default;

Which would indicate that the properties of parent are copied whole into child2.  In Javascript, objects (and therefore also arrays) are copied by reference.  _cache is an array, so when jQuery's extend method is copying objects from parent into child2, it copies a reference to the existing _cache Array rather than duplicating all of its values, so it ends up with a reference to the same array as parent.  A reference to that same array was also copied into child1 in the line prior.

When copying by reference, the references continue to point to the same object, and modifying that object using any one of its references will affect the original.